# BeautifulSoup new_tag inserted twice

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add several tags to div[id='head'] at once in a BeautifulSoup with

```
soup.find_all('div', id='head',limit=1)[0].insert(1, soup.new_tag(u'<div id="menu_top_right" class="menu_top"><div class="menu_inner"><a class="" target="_blank" href="./local/zkratky/index.html">Zkratky</a><span>|</span><a class="" target="_blank" href="./local/slovnik/index.html">Slovník</a><span>|</span><a class="" target="blank" href="./local/dokumenty/index.html">Dokumenty</a></div></div><div class="clear"></div>'))
```

As a result I got the code inserted twice (with some extra < and >), but have no idea why.

```
<<div id="menu_top_right" class="menu_top">
    <div class="menu_inner">
        <a class="" target="_blank" href="./local/zkratky/index.html">Zkratky</a><span>|</span>
        <a class="" target="_blank" href="./local/slovnik/index.html">Slovník</a><span>|</span>
        <a class="" target="blank" href="./local/dokumenty/index.html">Dokumenty</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>>
</<div id="menu_top_right" class="menu_top">
    <div class="menu_inner">
        <a class="" target="_blank" href="./local/zkratky/index.html">Zkratky</a><span>|</span>
        <a class="" target="_blank" href="./local/slovnik/index.html">Slovník</a><span>|</span>
        <a class="" target="blank" href="./local/dokumenty/index.html">Dokumenty</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>>
```

I didn't find anything in the docs saying you can't create several new tags with one soup.new_tag(). What might be the problem?

Comment: It seems, that `new_tag` already adds `<` and `>` to your tag, so remove `<` at start of your string and `>` from the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using you are using BeautifulSoup4? If you do, the problem is that you cannot create multiple tags with one `new_tag()`, let alone insert HTML:

```
>>> soup.new_tag('<div myattr="foo"></div>')
<<div myattr="foo"></div>></<div myattr="foo"></div>>
```

You must create each child seperately and assign the attributes manually:

```
>>> parent = soup.find('div')
>>> parent
<div></div>
>>> new_tag = soup.new_tag('div')
>>> new_tag['id'] = 'menu_top_right'
>>> new_tag['class'] = 'menu_top'
>>> new_tag
<div class="menu_top" id="menu_top_right"></div>
>>> parent.insert(1, new_tag)
>>> soup
<div><div class="menu_top" id="menu_top_right"></div></div>
```

Edit: The syntax highlighting makes this look weird.